# Load content over non-secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, ssl

I have an ASP.NET MVC site which is configured for HTTPS only.

One of the pages on this site needs to display content from a remote, non-SSL enabled website.

I cannot load the content in via ajax, as this will mean that non-secure content is mixed with my secure content and browsers will indicate that the site has mixed content.

So instead, I thought that I could load the content server-side using the `HttpClient` class using Web API, and then deliver it via AJAX to the client:

```
public async Task<string> GetNewsAsync()
{
    var newsFeed = WebConfig.GetAppSetting("NewsRssAddress");
    var feedContent = "";

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(newsFeed))
        using (var content = response.Content)
        {                                 
            feedContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Mailer.SendError(ex);
        throw;
    }
    return feedContent;
}
```

However, this still throws the `WebException`:

`System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

**DONT DO IT!**
*Having typed this, I am starting to think that what I am trying to do is just **bad practice and wrong**, and there is no way to load non-secure content into a secure site, kinda makes sense really, I mean, that content could be anything!*

As it happens, the site I am trying to load from is another one of my companies websites, its just that there is no SSL on the other site.

As far as I can tell, these are my options:

1. Don't load the content. period.
2. Try and get the other site an SSL certificate.
3. Deal with having the mixed content warning (I am not going to do this!)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing concepts a little there. The SSL implementation on your site is all about providing assurance to visitors that you are who you say you are and that the communication they're having with *you* has been encrypted in transit. That SSL implementation makes no assurances about the integrity of the content of the site; it could be completely malicious because you have a SQL injection vulnerability and you left anonymous FTP open on your site to boot. It's full of malware and goatse pics but the SSL still does exactly what it's meant to - serves it securely over the connection!

How the content on the page is populated is unrelated to how you serve it via HTTPS. You can definitely make HTTP requests *on the server side* from a resource requested over HTTPS. Give it a go here: https://asafaweb.com

Whether you *should* is another question; you have to assume that external resource request could be intercepted (or the site could be compromised independently of the transport layer) and you'd want to apply appropriate white-listing and verification of the content before re-displaying it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response Troy. Am I going about making the request in the wrong way then by using `HttpClient`? Why am I getting the `WebException`? Fair point about verifying the content, will look into that today but I expect this feature is more of a 'want' than a 'need' so might get away with telling stakeholders they can't have it.

Comment: I can't see anything you're doing wrong there, but I'd try proxying the request out through Fiddler and just being real sure of what it is you're trying to load and if, independently of your code, the request can actually be fulfilled. I'm using HttpWebRequest on ASafaWeb without drama, but HttpClient should be fine too. For a sanity check, load the page that makes the request over HTTP and see what happens - bet you it still fails!

Answer (score 0):

You can create "ssl" proxy for the other site. How to do this is describe on [Creating a Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite for IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) on adress like http://yoursite.com/othersite/something

This technique allows you to use same SSL for other site as for main site and also same origin.

But it is "heavy" because all request will got through your server

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. Still not sure that I should do this though, even if it is possible.